# How to add a comment before XML root node, in Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

This is what I'm doing:

```
xml = Nokogiri::XML('<hello/>')
xml.root.add_previous_sibling(
  Nokogiri::XML::Comment.new(
    xml, '<!-- how are you? -->'
  )
)
```

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- how are you? -->
<hello/>
```

I'm getting:

```
ArgumentError: A document may not have multiple root nodes.
```

What is the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment should be added inside `xml.children` NodeSet.
Here is an example:

```
 xml = Nokogiri::XML('<hello/>')
=> #<Nokogiri::XML::Document:0x3fe1db8d0ed0 name="document" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fe1db8d0584 name="hello">]>

xml.children.before(Nokogiri::XML::Comment.new(xml, 'how are you?'))
=> #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fe1db8d0584 name="hello">

xml.to_s
=> "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n<!--how are you?-->\n<hello/>\n"
```

Comment: I'm getting the same exception... Nokogiri 1.8.0

Comment: Are you sure your version is 1.8.0? I tried 1.7.0.1 and got exactly the same error as yours, but when I run this with 1.8.0 I don't have any error messages. 1.8.0 version has update to avoid this kind of error.